# Cannot mount Android phone and sync with Banshee

Tags: sync, banshee, android

I can't get my LG Optimus One to sync with Banshee. I read somewhere that the root needs to have an empty file called '.is_audio_player'.

I did that and it still doesn't mount.

I ran dmesg however and it appears that the card is unmounting before I even have a change to run Banshee.

```
[ 7250.321359] usb 1-1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 10
[ 7250.444795] scsi12 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
[ 7251.567946] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 7251.568839] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 7252.232433] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] 15564800 512-byte logical blocks: (7.96 GB/7.42 GiB)
[ 7252.233299] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 7252.233306] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 7252.233309] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 7252.235658] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 7252.235666]  sdc: sdc1
[ 7252.239132] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 7252.239140] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 7272.573437] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, address 10
```

Suggestions?

Comment: After you've plugged in the android device, are you hitting the usb symbol and setting mass storage mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the **empty** `.is_audio_player` file.

I have had a DROID and a DROID 2 Global and successfully synced ~10GB of music, both with the `.is_audio_file` in the root of the sdcard and the following contents:

```
audio_folders=data/Audio,amazonmp3/,media/,DCIM/
folder_depth=2
output_formats=application/ogg,audio/x-ms-wma,audio/mpeg,video/mp4,audio/x-aac,audio/aac,video/H263,video/H264,video/x-ms-wmv,audio/x-wav,audio/x-realaudio,audio/x-flac,audio/x-wavpack,audio/aacp,audio/x-musepack,audio/amr,audio/midi
```

I found the keys for these three settings in the source of either Banshee or Rhythmbox.  The folder depth is how many folders are created under the first audio_folder path when syncing.  So, for instance, this will give you `data/Audio/Artist/Album/Song.mp3`  If you were to change this to something like 8, you'd get `data/Audio/A/r/t/i/s/t....` or something similar.  I know, because my initial setting was 99 (I thought it was search depth).

Having amazonmp3 in the audio_folders path may cause Banshee to delete those mp3s, so be sure to pull them to the computer either manually or through Banshee before syncing.

Answer (score 0):

I always found it very helpful to add a new rule for the device like it says on the android website

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

LG is 1004